# How do you mock object in a static method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

If I have something like this:

```
static class ManifestGenerator
{
    public static void GenerateManifestFile(){
    var doc = new XDocument();
    ...
    ... xml stuff added to doc
    ...
    doc.Save(manifestFilePath)
}
```

Now can you please tell me how can I create a unit test that will ensure that the method generates correct xml?
How can I mock XDocument (I am using Moq), without adding additional parameters to the method call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't try to mock `XDocument`. That's not the problem here - it's the access to the file system which is annoying. You could pass in a `Stream` to write the manifest to instead:

```
public static void GenerateManifestFile(Stream output) {
  var doc = new XDocument();
  ...
  ... xml stuff added to doc
  ...
  doc.Save(output);
}
```

Then you can test that with a `MemoryStream`, but use a `FileStream` to the manifest path in reality. You might even make this method internal (using `[InternalsVisibleTo]` so you can still access it from tests) and a public parameterless overload along the lines of:

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(manifestFilePath))
{
    GenerateManifestFile(output);
}
```

You then don't test *that* code, but you can test all your real logic.

Comment: +1: splitting it into `using`-part in public method + internal worker is really good tip.